# How to disable Auto Save in Xcode 4.6?

Tags: xcode, autosave

I tried to no avail

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode ApplePersistence -bool NO
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ApplePersistence -bool NO
```

The "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" option from 4.2 has been removed, https://discussions.apple.com/message/20435985#20435985.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn System Preferences -> General -> "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" on.

It's still there as of OS X 10.8.3.

Comment: Thanks!
I misread (skimmed) https://discussions.apple.com/message/20435985#20435985 thinking it was refering to Xcode's preferences.

Comment: The suggested answer isn't working for me, unfortunately. I have selected "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" in System Preferences / General. I open an Xcode project, I make a change, I build and run to see the effect, I close the project (not wanting this temporary change to save), and I am *not* asked whether to save my changes (undesired behavior). If I reopen the project, I see the changes were saved. If I make a change and do not build/run, I *am* asked whether I want to save changes upon closing the project (desired behavior).

Comment: Same problem, xCode 8.3.3