# Xcode 6.4 auto save disable

Tags: ios, xcode

When I exit Xcode it save project. I do not want that. How to disable auto save in Xcode 6.4? I did not find option in preferences. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468313/how-to-disable-auto-save-in-xcode-4-6 ?!

Comment: thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use system configuration to fix that issue. Do next:

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Open the General panel.
3. Check "Ask to keep changes when closing documents"

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've found that this (System Preferences) setting works but only if you don't use Command-Q to quit XCode. If you use the red close button at the top of the window it will prompt you, but not otherwise. Why does Apple do things in the least-helpful way sometimes? Why can't they be normal!

Comment: Same problem and this didn't help. Apple is...Interesting sometimes.